# How to show BufferedImages in SWT project?

Tags: java, swing, swt, awt, bufferedimage

I'm working on an SWT project, but I will be working extensively with `Awt.Robot.createScreenCapture()` to generate BufferedImages. I will have hundreds - thousands of images generated in this way.

The problem is, SWT doesn't seem capable of showing BufferedImages , and has its own `Image` class. I know that its possible to convert BufferedImages to SWT's Image, but SWT's images seem to need to be disposed manually and don't have automatic garbage collection like Swing's BufferedImage would.

Plus, I imagine it'd take time / effort for the computer to be constantly converting from BufferedImage to Image, which could likely slow down my program, which isn't acceptable as its a time critical application.

So, is there a way to show the BufferedImages on a SWT `Shell`? (I'll probably have a `Jpanel` showing the image for each of the images, so I just need a way to show the JPanel onto the `Shell`.)

Comment: Either use the [swt/awt bridge](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html) or show the images in a popup jframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried SWT/AWT Bridge as suggested in the comment to your question and it works as expected:

```
    static BufferedImage bim;

static Frame frame;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                try {
                    final java.awt.Rectangle screenRect = new java.awt.Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
                    bim = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
                    frame.repaint();
                    Thread.sleep(100);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }).start();

    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    shell.setSize(200, 200);

    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
    frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(new JPanel() {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(bim, 0, 0, this);
        }

    }, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! One question, if I wanted to show multiple of these images (e.g 4-5), how would I do that? What would I have to do to make a reusable `BufferedImageContainer` or such class which I can just add to my `shell`s repeatedly (and call `setImage(myBufferedImage)` to set the image?)

Comment: "multiple images" as tiles on the same panel?

Comment: I think each image should be in its own Java frame / composite so I can place them wherever I need to